# Java binary search already sorted list

Tags: java, list, binary-search

I've a DB query using **ORDERED BY**  and the corresponding result set is processed to a list of custom objects.

The object class does not implement Comparable . It however overrides **equals() and hashcode()** using the same field as used in **ORDERED BY** .

Since the list is already sorted , how can I do a binary search of the list using the sorted field as key and without comparable or **comparator**?

Comment: Very nice question.

Answer (score 3):

In a word - you can't. At least not with the JDK's binary search. `Comparable`s and `Comparator`s are the way java expresses order. This shouldn't be an issue, though. Even if you can't change the data class, you can always use your own (anonymous) `Comparator`:

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(myArray, 
                                myObject,
                                Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getSomeField));
```

Comment: So I don't first have to sort the array as it is already sorted or i have to sort also and then use binarysearch method ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur according to OP, the array is already sorted, so there's no point in sorting it again.

Comment: will the sorting order matter i mean if my sorted data is in ascending or descending will binarysearch method work for both case ?? I am asking this because as in sorting aslo we have to pass comparator and as we are not sorting acc to comparator so will there be any issue or not ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur it will work in as long as the Comparator you provide (the third argument) matches the order the array is sorted by

Comment: but as i have not sorted my data acc to comparator so don't you think may be it is possible that my order is reverse then the order which comparator is expecting ?? Consider case i have 1,2,3,4,5 but may be comparator will sort it 5,4,3,2,1 will still binary search method work or not ?? please explain ??

Comment: It is working for both order (ascending and as well as in descending).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use existing JDK methods like `Collections.binarySearch`, you'll have to implement a `Comparator<YourCustomClass>` (since you class doesn't implement `Comparable`).

If you don't want to implement `Comparator<YourCustomClass>`, you'll have to implement the entire binary search logic yourself, which is more work than just implementing `Comparator<YourCustomClass>`.